# What does Narada mean by when he says "those Asuras.......who sprang from Vishnu"?

Tags: vishnu, mahabharata, asuras, narada

> Here dwell, O Matali, those Asuras called Kalakhanjas **who sprang from
>   Vishnu**, and those Rakshasas also called Yatudhanas who sprang from the
>   feet of Brahman.[Udyoga Narada Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05100.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The Devas and Asuras in the Hindu saga are actually direct descendants of Lord Vishnu.

Lord Brahma is born on a Lotus that grew from the navel of Lord Vishnu. So, Brahma is considered to be the son of Vishnu.

> स पद्मकोशः सहसोदतिष्ठ-
>
> त्कालेन कर्मप्रतिबोधनेन ।
>
> स्वरोचिषा तत्सलिलं विशालं
>
> विद्योतयन्नर्क इवात्मयोनिः ॥१४
>
> With the Time that roused the karma to activity, soon from the
>   original self [of Vishnu] with that [agitation] a lotus bud appeared
>   that, just like a sun, illumined the vast waters with its effulgence.
>
> तल्लोकपद्मं स उ एव विष्णुः
>
> प्रावीविशत्सर्वगुणावभासम् ।
>
> तस्मिन् स्वयं वेदमयो विधाता
>
> स्वयंभुवं यं स्म वदन्ति सोऽभूत् ॥१५॥
>
> That lotus flower of factually the universe was entered by Vishnu as
>   the reservoir of all qualities from which He in the beginning
>   generated the personality of Vedic wisdom, the controller of the
>   universe [Brahma] who, so one says, was born from himself.
>
> श्रीमद् भागवतम् स्कन्धं 3, अध्यायं 8, श्लोकं 14–15
>
> Sreemad Bhagavatham Canto 3, Chapter 8, Verses 14–15

The first Sapta Rishis were born from Brahma and one among them was Marichi.

> पुलहो नाभितो जज्ञे पुलस्त्यः कर्णयोः ऋषिः ।
>
> अङ्गिरा मुखतोऽक्ष्णोऽत्रिर्मरीचिर्मनसोऽभवत् ।।
>
> Pulaha generated from the navel, Pulastya from his ears, the great
>   sage Angira from the mouth, from the eyes sage Atri came forth and
>   sage Marichi appeared from the mind of Lord Brahma.
>
> श्रीमद् भागवतम् स्कन्धं 3, अध्यायं 12, श्लोकं 24
>
> Sreemad Bhagavatham Canto 3, Chapter 12, Verse 24.
>
> Sage Kashyapa is the son of Sage Marichi.
>
> दितिर्दाक्षायणी क्षत्तर्मारीचं कश्यपं पतिम् ।
>
> अपत्यकामा चकमे सन्ध्यायां हृच्छयार्दिता ॥७ ॥
>
> One evening Diti, the daughter of Daksha, in distress because of
>   desire begged her husband Kashyapa, the son of Marichi, to father a
>   child.
>
> श्रीमद् भागवतम् स्कन्धं 3, अध्यायं 14, श्लोकं 7
>
> Sreemad Bhagavatham Canto 3, Chapter 14, Verse 7
>
> Kashyapa had multiple wives, the most prominent ones among them being
>   Diti and Aditi.
>
> The sons of Diti came to be known as Daityas while the sons of Aditi
>   are renowned as Adityas.
>
> Another of Kashyapa's wives, Danu, gave birth to another group of
>   Asuras known as Danavas.

So all asurs, danavs etc etc are all decendant of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Vishnu was the BAAP of every asura...

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker what do you mean to say?

Comment: That he was indirectly their father.